# How to print query of Django ORM

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django, orm

I am using Django ORM query with Extra params. when I try to print the SQL query relevant to that ORM Query,i am getting the below Error message.

**ORM Query**:

Record = SAMPLE_TABLE.objects.extra(where=["REPLACE(**Message**,' ','') "+**whereCaseSensitive**+" like %s "+**query**],params=[**duplicateCheckMessage**]).filter(~Q(iStatus=2),~Q(iAppStatus=2),iEntityID=entityId,iTemplateType=1).first()

Message - FieldName ,
whereCaseSensitive - '',
query - ( FIND_IN_SET("test",Testfield))

I am trying to fetch the sql query related to this using
print(Record.query)
when i run this i am getting Exception as **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'query'**

Can any one help on this ?

Comment: i think your query is not valid. if Record is NoneType, it means extra a return nothing, so probably the generated query is not valid. Are you sure you can use REPLACE function in a WHERE clause ?

Comment: @LucasGrugru , yes the is correct. I just customized it w.r.to my requirement. Even if the Query return None , I need to get the SQL Query what is getting Executed ri8?

Answer (score 0):

You can't print the query for the first (or any) element of a queryset because it is an instance, not a query. To print `.query` you need to do it on the queryset

Try this

```
my_query = SAMPLE_TABLE.objects.extra(*some_extra).filter(*some_filter)
print(my_query.query)
record = my_query.first()
```